# Matrix Multiplication Dimension - but with tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors

## Matrices

If I have two matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ I only require the number of columns of $A$ and the number of rows of $B$ to the the same to do matrix multiplication. The resulting dimension can be found by "eliminating" this common dimension
$$
AB \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}
$$

## Tensors

Suppose now I have some three-dimensional tensors $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m\times p}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times r\times s}$. I would like to compute
$$
CD
$$

What dimensionality requirements do we need and what is the dimension of the resulting tensor after doing tensor multiplication?

My intuition is that we require $m=q$ for this to work.

Comment: There is no "standard" analogue to matrix multiplication for two three-dimensional tensors. However, the kind of operation you're doing is sometimes referred to as a [contraction of a pair of tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Contraction_of_a_pair_of_tensors).

Comment: Is there any particular thing that you're hoping to do with the "product" $CD$, or are you just trying to make sense of what $CD$ might mean for tensors $C,D$?